# How can I retrieve a ViewModel associated with an Activity from a custom view?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm, android-viewmodel

I can manage to retrieve a ViewModel associated with a Fragment but not with an Activity.

**This works :**

-Fragment-

```
private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()
```

-Custom View-

```
private val mainViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(findViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner()!!).get<MainViewModel>()
}
```

**But not that :**

-Fragment-

```
private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

-Custom View-

```
private val mainViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(findViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner()!!).get<MainViewModel>()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by casting the Activity of the custom View to ViewModelStoreOwner and getting a ViewModel from ViewModelProvider created with this Activity :

```
private val mainViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(context as ViewModelStoreOwner).get<MainViewModel>()
}
```